# Jquery conflict in navigation manu wordpress

Tags: jquery, ajax, wordpress, conflict

I need to use these two files of jquery. But these are conflict. How can I use these two files without conflict.

```
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.0/jquery.min.js"></script> 
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.3.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: No, you don't need to use those two files, and certainly not jQuery 1.3

Comment: I need to fixed navigation for this purpose JQ 1.3 needed

Comment: If you are really sure you actually need both jquery versions and can't migrate your code to just all use the same version, then you could rename the jQuery symbol in one of the versions, e.g. call it jQurery_1_3_0 instead of jQuery. For this to work you will obviously need to download the jQuery file and produce your own modified version. You will naturally also need to use jQuery.noconflict - http://api.jquery.com/jquery.noconflict/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should use noconflict method for this purpost. See below:

First load 1.11.0

`<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.0/jquery.min.js"></script>`

`<script type="text/javascript">` 
  `var jQuery_1_11_0 = $.noConflict(true);`
  `<script>`

Now load 1.3.0

`<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.3.0/jquery.min.js"></script>`

`<script type="text/javascript">` 
`var jQuery_1_3_0 = $.noConflict(true);`
`<script>`

Now, use jQuery_1_11_0('#selector').function(); or jQuery_1_3_0('#selector').function();

instead of $('#selector').function();

Answer (score 1):

You don't need use both of them, jQuery 1.11.0 will do all for you.
if you use old plugins that use 1.3.0 you can change it to work with 1.11.0 too.
it's not hard to trace and find why your plugin dosn't work with 1.11.0
also you can use migration tools.